# how to save image in PLT

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm trying to save my result image using `matplotlib.pyplot` as the following code which works good without any problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
I = image.astype(np.uint8)
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(I) 
plt.plot(marker_x, marker_y, color='yellow')# our circle 
ax.set_title('Macula')
plt.savefig("J://uni//final project//res_image//marked_M.png")
fig.show()
```

here is my saved picture `plt.savefig("J://uni//final project//res_image//marked_M.png")` :

[image]

the yellow circle is a `plot` and as you know when we use `plt.plot` automatically we have a white space around the main picture (sth like margin as you see in the picture ) and also the axes

and its my 'tkinter' UI:
[image]

I'm wondering if is any way to crop this annoying white space or save image in another way that we get rid of this margin?

Comment: Why not just set the face color to the same color as your GUI? `fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')`

Comment: @Novel `fig.patch.set_facecolor('black')` just work on my pycharm but after I save the image and show it in the  GUI its not work and the problem is still there as @Halmon said below we could  do this `plt.savefig("J://uni//final project//res_image//marked_M.png", transparent=True)` thank you for answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the matplotlib `transparent` flag

```
plt.savefig("J://uni//final project//res_image//marked_M.png", transparent=True)
```

This will save the image as a png file with a transparent background